# Not sure how I am supposed to keep this Arraylist from being editable

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this class, Party, in which I have an `arraylist` RSVP and an `arraylist` invited. The goal is that One should be able to add a name to these `arraylists` using my `addInvited()` and get it using `getInvited()`. I know the problem is in one of these two methods, as every other method has passed its test. I need to make it so that someone can add a Person object using addInvited(), but that Person CANNOT change his name. I can't seem to figure out if I'm just not making a deep enough copy, or what...

```
    package lab04partB;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Party {
    private ArrayList<Person>   invited;
    private ArrayList<Person>   RSVP;

    public Party() {
        invited = new ArrayList<Person>();
        RSVP = new ArrayList<Person>();
    }

    public void addInvited(Person person) {
        if (!invited.contains(person)) {
            Person JohnDoe = new Person(person.getName());
            invited.add(JohnDoe);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Person> getInvited() {
        ArrayList<Person> tempList = new ArrayList<Person>(invited);
        return tempList;
    }

    public void addRSVP(Person person) {
        if ((!RSVP.contains(person)) && (invited.contains(person))) {
            Person JaneDoe = new Person(person.getName());
            RSVP.add(JaneDoe);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Person> getRSVP() {
        ArrayList<Person> tempList = new ArrayList<Person>(RSVP);
        return tempList;
    }

    }
```

Here is the test it is running against, if it helps!

```
@Test
public void testGetInvitedModifyNamesReturned() {
    Party  party = new Party();
    Person a     = new Person( new String( KANY_GARCIA   ));
    Person b     = new Person( new String( LAURA_PAUSINI ));

    party.addInvited( a );
    party.addInvited( b );

    ArrayList<Person> list = party.getInvited();
    assertEquals( 2, list.size() );
    for (Person p : list) {
        p.setName( new String( MIGUEL_RIOS ));
    }

    list = party.getInvited();
    assertEquals( "Incorrect result", 2, list.size() );
    assertTrue  ( "Incorrect result", list.contains( a ));
    assertTrue  ( "Incorrect result", list.contains( b ));
}
```

Comment: What is the issue ? you are not able to add name or you are not able to make the "name" uneditable ?

Comment: Well I need to make it so that "Any person can be added to the list, as long as the person is not in the list already. To avoid  people that could be added to the list and then change their names, you should create a new person using the name of the person passed as a parameter and add this newly created person to the list"

Comment: What does your person object look like?

Comment: Here is the person class: http://pastebin.com/T8Kh0qyv

Comment: When returning the `Person` from the `Party`, maybe create a new instance of them, inserting them into a new `List` and returning that copy

Comment: It's probably beyond the scope of your assignment, but maybe you should use an interface called `Person` which only has getters and an interface which extends from `Person` (`MutablePerson`) which has the setters, this way you can restrict the expectations of the API

Comment: I thought that was what I was doing in addInvited(), creating a new object with the name of the object passed as a parameter. I don't know if i quite understand your comment otherwise

Comment: ah geez, interfaces. I should have mentioned I'm relatively new, I don't quite know what that is.

Comment: @PatrickGeery I was thinking you do it the other way, rather then doing it in `addInvited`, you do it in `getInvited` ;)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to make the `name` field in the `Person` class `final` but then no one can change the name of a person anywhere. Guess that is not what you want.

Alternatively you can create an inner class in `Party` that subclasses `Person` and disallows changing the name. Then when you add a person to a party you first convert the input argument to an immutable person.

```
class Party {

    private static final class ImmutablePerson extends Person {

        public ImmutablePerson(String name) {
            super(name);
        }

        @Override
        void setName(String s) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot change name");
            // or just do nothing here
        }

    }

    public void addInvited(Person person) {
        ImmutablePerson immutable = new ImmutablePerson(person.getName());
        if (!invited.contains(immutable)) {
            invited.add(immutable);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this. I do not know if I can include throw/catch exception stuff yet, since we haven't learned it, but I will try to sneak it in haha.

I'm not quite sure how you would like me to 'convert the input argument to an immutable person.'

Comment: @PatrickGeery if you do not want to throw an exception, just let the method do nothing :)

Comment: Ok. but then how would you have me 'convert the input argument to an immutable person' after i implement what you have given me?

Comment: @PatrickGeery just as in the `addInvited()` method in the code that is in my answer

Comment: That is up to you but I would create it inside the Party class

Answer (score 0):

Make `Person` [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). It's actually best practice too, because people don't change data, and (as here) you can safely publish them.

Comment: But maybe other parts of the program need to change the name?

Comment: @martin even though that issue is out of scope for this question, just create a new person object!

Comment: that might cause other issues and you might end up with inconsistent data - but yes this is out of scope ^^

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you might be able to do this...

You could use interfaces to maintain the contractual expectations of the API, so you could setup non-mutable version of `Person` (with getters) and a mutable version (with setters), this would mean that your `Party` class could return the non-mutable types, preventing people from directly modifying the values.

This could lead to using the non-mutable instance as a wrapper for the mutable version, further preventing people from casting the results to get around this.

Something like...

```
public interface Person extends Comparable<Person> {
    public String getName();
}

public class DefaultPerson implements Person {

    private String name;

    public DefaultPerson(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Person)) {
            return false;
        }
        final Person other = (Person) obj;
        if ((this.name == null) ? (other.name != null) : !this.name.equals(other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 37 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.name);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person arg0) {
        return arg0.getName().compareTo(name) * -1;
    }

    public Character[] toCharacterArray(String s) {

        if (s == null) {
            return null;
        }

        int len = s.length();
        Character[] array = new Character[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            array[i] = new Character(s.charAt(i));
        }

        return array;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }

}
```

Then your `Party` might look something like...

```
public static class Party {

    private ArrayList<Person> invited;
    private ArrayList<Person> RSVP;

    public Party() {
        invited = new ArrayList<Person>();
        RSVP = new ArrayList<Person>();
    }

    public void addInvited(Person person) {
        if (!invited.contains(person)) {
            invited.add(person);
        }
    }

    public List<Person> getInvited() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(invited);
    }

    public void addRSVP(Person person) {
        if ((!RSVP.contains(person)) && (invited.contains(person))) {
            RSVP.add(person);
        }
    }

    public List<Person> getRSVP() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(RSVP);
    }

}
```

The class know only deals with `Person` types, which are not mutable (okay, you could create instances of `DefaultPerson` and add them to your lists, which would prevent the caller from modifying the names, but that's up to you)

The class also makes use `Collections.unmodifiableList` which prevents the `List` from been modified by the caller! Bonus :)

It would then mean, doing something like...

```
List<Person> list = party.getInvited();
for (Person p : list) {
    p.setName(new String("Whelma"));
}
```

would be impossible, because `setName` is not a method of `Person`!

## But...

that might be beyond the scope of your assignment, instead, when you return the list of invitees, you could create new instances of the values then, for example...

```
public void addInvited(Person person) {
    if (!invited.contains(person)) {
        invited.add(person);
    }
}

public ArrayList<Person> getInvited() {
    ArrayList<Person> tempList = new ArrayList<>(invited.size());
    for (Person p : invited) {
        tempList.add(new Person(p.getName()));
    }
    return tempList;
}
```

This is less the optimal, but it would allow your code to pass the tests you have.

I should also point out, `equals` has a contractual relationship with `hashcode`, from the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

Basically, what this means is, if you override `equals` you must also override `hashcode` (and visa-versa)